# Cannot close Match window in Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Firstly I go to
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
with my Chrome browser (v.51.0.2704.106 m) on Windows 7.

[image]

After I clicked the matches button, another window appeared for more detailed information.

[image]

When wanted to close it, the **(x)** button didn't work. Then I tried the **(Cancel)** button. But it also didn't work.

Is this bug or something relevant to my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that was a bug. There was a script missing from the /jobs page. It's there now. Thanks for the report!